# First received byte array from a device is always wrong

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port

I'm writing a program which will write an array through the serialport containing 6 bytes and then the responding device will respond with an array containing 6 bytes. The read data then will be proccessed and displayed in the windows form application. First byte is command, second byte is ID, third and fourth byte is argument, last two bytes are the CRC. My problem is that when I send the array, the first responding array is always received either wrong or '0 0 0 0 0 0', and sometimes the bytes in the array shift places. But after one or two arrays the following arrays are correct.

An example of wrong received array:

Sent array: 16 5 0 0 65 15
Received array: 165 0 0 0 0 0

An example of shifted array:

Sent array: 16 5 0 0 65 15
Received array: 0 165 0 0 0 0

An example of null array:

Sent array: 16 5 0 0 65 15
Received array: 0 0 0 0 0 0

Here is my current method of reading the data is:

```cs
private void SerialRead()
{
    while (SerialEnable)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        int bytesRead = Sp.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            byte num = buffer[0];

            switch (SerialByteCounter)
            {
                case 0:
                    ReceivedBytes[SerialByteCounter] = num;
                    ++SerialByteCounter;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (num == id)
                    {
                        ReceivedBytes[SerialByteCounter] = num;
                        ++SerialByteCounter;
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ReceivedBytes[SerialByteCounter] = num;
                    ++ReceiveCounter;
                    ParseMessage();
                    SerialByteCounter = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    ReceivedBytes[SerialByteCounter] = num;
                    ++SerialByteCounter;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my method of checking the sent and received array's:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("BytesToSend:");
foreach (byte b in BytesToSend)
{
    Console.Write(b + " ");
}

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("ReceivedBytes:");
foreach (byte b in ReceivedBytes)
{
    Console.Write(b + " ");
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

I also tried the Sp.ReadByte(); method. This problem also happens in QT Creator aswell. Could this be a problem on my end, or could the operating system not proccesing the received data correctly? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: i don't see the connection to Winforms or QT. You are simply using the Frameworks SerialPort class and write result to the Console? That the byte 16 followed by a byte 5 get translated somehow to a byte 165 is weird do you really see that?

Comment: You are talking of another "device" here so i maybe misunderstood some details here. Does this "device" do anything with the data you send to it? Can you check what it does with the data send to it and you then get responded from it?

Comment: I have different projects on both Winforms and QT. The problem persists in both programs. I check the arrays in the Console to see whether the arrays are corrupted or not, the main objective is to save the data on the dictionary and display it in multiple forms with different identifiers. The byte 16 and byte 5 do not get translated into byte 165, I gave the respond array as an example response from a device. It can change when I restart the program. There is a communication protocol between the computer and the device which both answer to. The command byte is the first byte in the array.

Comment: @KeremM. So the problem is about serial port management, the toolkit is irrelevant. Please only use tags that are relevant to the problem.